# In MPAndroidChart negative values are not displayed on chart coordinates

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) i tried to make following two charts. Following images are self explanatory: one is when y-axis is positive and other when it is negative(here the values of the chart aren't visible): [Positive Axis Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOb2P.jpg)  [Negative Axis Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abw2X.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide your code, the desired result and explain where it goes wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cannot post the code due to company policy. and as you can see in "positive axis chart" values are visible inside chart, whereas in "negative axis chart" the values aren't visible. the result that i expect is values visible in "negative axis chart" as well.

Answer (score 5):

keep below code in Main thread where you initialized the chart. It will work fine.

```
    chart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
    chart2.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set setStartAtZero(false). There are many methods to control values range on axis. Please read [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki).

[Check this also](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki)

Comment: Hi seema, 
I have already used the function that you have mentioned. Wasn't of any help!

Answer (score 2):

setStartAtZero is deprecated.

if you get the values from database, try this:

```
    //your Y values
    float min = Collections.min(arrayY);

    //set your min value like this
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(min);
```